# Multiple lines for Google translate API (v2) and PHP (Symfony) requests problem

Tags: php, arrays, rest, google-translate, google-translation-api

In my application, which uses Symfony and Google Translate API (v2), I have the following simple code:

```
$textArray = ["this is my text", "my text is amazing"];

$options = [
    'body' => [
        'q' => $textArray,
        'target' => $targetLocale,
        'format' => $format,
        'source' => $locale,
        'model' => 'base',
        'key' => $this->parameterBag->get('google_api_key')
    ],
    'headers' => [
        'ContentType' => 'application/json'
    ]
];
$response = $this->client->request(
    'POST',
    $this->parameterBag->get('google_translate_api.v2.translate_path'),
    $options
);
```

I use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface for the requests.
So, the my $options are the following:
[image: $options variable]

In response I get a 400 error. So, during debugging I found out that the problem is in the "q" - it expects a string, not array. The official documentation says that I should send the array of strings there if I have multiple sentences, at least I have such option.
When I send them through Postman using the same "q" keys, everything works fine.
[image: in Postman works well]

So, the question is: how should I modify my array of Qs in order to make it work?

Comment: Their REST example in the documentation makes a JSON request, have you tried that?

Comment: @CBroe, it is a JSON request, when I sent 'q' => 'my random string', it works. any ideas how could it be solved?

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would make it a JSON request? And in your postman screenshot, you are sending `form-data`, whereas I suspect your code above would rather send form-urlencoded?

Comment: @CBroe, I've updated it with the header, but it still didn't help. what should I do? as I said, it works, when I send a string instead of array but documentation says, it is possible to send array.

Comment: Still doubt that you are actually sending JSON there. https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#uploading-data says, _"When uploading JSON payloads, use the `json` option instead of `body`. The given content will be JSON-encoded automatically and the request will add the Content-Type: application/json automatically too"_

Comment: @CBroe I've updated it with "json" instead of "body", but really nothing changed. That crashes when I send the array for 'q' and works fine when it is a string. The documentation (https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v2/translate) says the following: "q : string : Required The input text to translate. Provide an array of strings to translate multiple phrases. The maximum number of strings is 128." so, I need to send something like this: ['q'=>["string1","string2","string128"]]. but it doesn't allow me to do this

Comment: @CBroe Postman basically sends it like this: ['q'=>'string1', 'q'=>'string2', 'q' => 'string3'] so it works, but I can't achieve it programmatically and seems like the idea of arrays is to have a unique key, so I don't understand what to do with it and how normally that should work.

Comment: PHP will overwrite GET/POST parameters with the same name, unless the name gets square brackets appended - and therefor it does not really have a build-in mechanism to create a different query string format. `http_build_query` would create you a query string format with URL-encoded brackets including an index - try `preg_replace('/%5B\d+%5D/', '', http_build_query($body))` to get one without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was actually is in using 'json instead of 'body' and the thing that we need to pass the key in 'query', not in 'json', separately.

```
$options = [
    'json' => [
        'q' => $textArray,
        'target' => $targetLocale,
        'format' => $format,
        'source' => $locale,
        'model' => 'base',
    ],
    'query' => [
        'key' => $this->parameterBag->get('google_api_key'),
    ]
];
```

this way we will have a possibility to send a proper array as array of Q strings.